# Open source PDF viewer for Linux with JavaScript support

Tags: linux, open-source, pdf, pdf-viewer

Requirements:

- Basic PDF support
- Form support
- At least basic JavaScript support
- Open source

Ideally:

- Packaged for Debian
- vi-style keybindings (jklh to move around, etc.)
- Minimal interface (hidden-by-default or non-existent statusbar/toolbar)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by JavaScript support? How does that relate to PDF viewing?

Comment: @BasilBourque, some PDFs have JavaScript code in them, eg. to have form elements update based on other form elements. I believe it's a non-standard Adobe extension.

Comment: For those curious, see this Stack Overflow question, [Using Javascript inside a PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9219807/642706).

Comment: Looks like there is no answer, unfortunately, at the moment. So far, the only software I can use that allows me to open pdf embedding javascript forms (and fill them, press buttons etc.) is master pdf editor (but it's more an editor than a viewer and unfortunately not open source).

Comment: Also, it seems that Adobe Acrobat Reader is back on Ubuntu (maybe debian?), so it's another (not open source) workaround: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/4-best-linux-pdf-viewers/

Comment: Are you referring to auto-filling fields with formulas using javascript? in that case this may help: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/48183/linux-pdf-reader-that-supports-forms-with-formulas

Comment: Putting together PDF and javascript functionalities is the classic recipe to make the usual can of worms. We lost the count of the number of viruses spread via infected documents a long time ago.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a full solution because the following application is not open source. However it seems to have more than basic JavaScript support, and most navigation options can be customized (to create vi-style keybindings). Notably it is the only application I found on Linux that shows interactive tooltips created by the tex [fancytooltip](https://ctan.org/pkg/fancytooltips?lang=en) package.

The application I am refering to is [**PDF-XChange Editor**](https://www.tracker-software.com/product/pdf-xchange-editor) which works well with Wine on X11 (on Wayland it causes a system freeze up).

Of course I am interested in any other application that shows fancy tooltips, but I tried Qoppa, Foxit, Okular, Evince PDF viewer and also Master PDF Editor; none of them showed fancy tooltips.
Most of these applications support basic JavaScript, which answers the question I guess. Of these applications Okular can be fully customized to obtain a minimal interface and set vi-style keybindings.

Comment: According to @dalanicolai , there is a wonderful replacement for package fancytooltips:
[https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/509807/how-can-i-change-the-shape-of-tooltip-box/509838#509838](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/509807/how-can-i-change-the-shape-of-tooltip-box/509838#509838) Which support Evince.