# Linux PDF reader that supports forms with formulas

Tags: linux, javascript, pdf-viewer, forms

I am trying to fill out a Yu-Gi-Oh deck list for a tournament on my Linux Mint 18.3 machine.

FORM: http://www.yugioh-card.com/en/events/forms/KDE_DeckList.pdf

The problem is that there is a "formula" or script of some kind that occurs in columns, you fill in a number (only 1-3 is allowed) in column one, then the number of cards you have, and at the bottom of that column it totals it for you automatically, and it totals top for all columns (Main Deck Total is Total Monster Cards+Spell Cards+Trap Cards).

The problem is, I cannot find a Linux PDF reader that these formulas work in. In every application I have tried it leaves the totals at zero or blank. I believe these formulas are some kind of Javascript, because if I enter an invalid value (like 4 for example), I get a "Warning: JavaScript Window - Invalid value: must be greater than or equal to 1 and less than or equal to 3."

The screenshot is from Acrobat Reader DC in Windows and gives the expected result... I have tried several Linux applications including Okular, Xreader, and Evince and they all failed to total the columns or "total" box, leaving them zero or blank and uneditable.

I am looking for software, preferably FOSS, that can support this PDF file and allow to properly fill out the form. I know this can be done in Chrome, but it does not allow the filled out form to be saved... which is another requirement.

[image: Deck List screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try our PDF Reader, it supports filling interactive forms and it supports JavaScript for formatting, calculating, validating, etc..

https://www.qoppa.com/pdfstudioviewer/

PS: I am developer and owner at Qoppa, the company that publishes this application.

Comment: This does EXACTLY what I was looking for, thank you!!! Sorry for not trying it out and getting back sooner. My only suggestion would be to modernize the deb package so it will populate the DE menu on most Linux distributions, in Linux Mint Mate and Cinnamon it did not add the entry to the GUI "start" menu and I had to add it manually. But the functionality of the software is just what I needed.